# $\lim (t_nx_n + (1-t_n)y_n) =a $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove if for each $n \in \mathbb N$, $0 \leq t_n \leq 1$ and  $\lim x_n = \lim y_n = a$ then the $\lim (t_nx_n + (1-t_n)y_n) =a $

I tried to do like this
$t_nx_n + (1-t_n)y_n$ = $t_n(x_n - y_n) + y_n$ 
Using that $t_n$ is bounded and $(x_n - y_n) \rightarrow 0$

I am not very confident in $(1-t_n)y_n = y_n - t_ny_n$ step only having that $t_n$ is bounded.

Thanks for any help.. if this question is duplicate, please forgive me and comment with the answer.

Comment: Do you really mean you wonder if the distributive law depends on the bounded nature of $t_n$? $(a-b)c=ac-bc$ all the time.

Comment: thank you @ThomasAndrews.. I have doubt about that when is sequence.. Let $S_n = 1 - 1 - 1 - 1..$ when you multiple by -1 both sides and add 1 .. you got $S_n = 1/2$ ..  and that is against the result of series .. the main term will not goes to 0. And $S_n$ is a bounded sequence.. when i multiple sequence without knowing whether it is convergent .. i have doubts.

Comment: We're not apply distribution on a series, we are applying it to many single expressions, $t_n(1-x_n)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for your comments and hint..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the boundedness argument; I'd feel more comfortable tackling this with an $N$-$\epsilon$ proof (probably overkill, but here we go):
Adding in $\pm t_na$ terms:
\begin{align*}|(t_nx_n+(1-t_n)y_n)-a| &= |(t_nx_n+(1-t_n)y_n)-a -t_na+t_na| \\
& = |t_nx_n - t_na + y_n-a - (t_ny_n-t_na)| \\
& \leq |t_n||x_n-a|+|y_n-a|+|t_n||y_n-a| \\
& \leq |x_n-a|+2|y_n-a|,
\end{align*}
where the last line follows from $|t_n|\leq 1$. Thus for $\epsilon>0$, we can find a large enough $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies the above terms are $<\epsilon/3$. Adding up completes the proof.

Comment: thank you @Glare, very nice.. but you are using distributive law in the second line $t_ny_n$ i think this have no problem and i am making a mistake ..  any way . thank you

Comment: The reason why I could use distributivity is because this is for a **fixed** integer $n$. You're correct in saying (as you did in your original post) that we can't do this *inside* the limit (where $n$ is changing), but when we move from the limit to the limit definition we can use all the regular properties of numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation and the proof you posted here.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that $\left|t_n(x_n-y_n)\right|\leq |x_n-y_n|$ and $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$.